# How can I run a Windows executable from WSL (Ubuntu) Bash

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Along with *Windows 10 Anniversary update* for summer 2016, came the possibility to run *ubuntu* binaries inside the new [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/), a "lightweight" virtualized subsystem.

Unfortunately, launching `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`, another `bash` ELF binary starts a process inside the WSL, from where you cannot escape!  You may launch only other ELF binaries.

So how can I execute `*.exe` files from Windows Bash?[1]

[1] Question asked also in [Microsoft's "official" GH support repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/333).

Comment: See also [Bash on Windows - alias for exe files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185086/bash-on-windows-alias-for-exe-files) for workarounds to avoid requirement to add explicit `.exe` extensions in shell scripts.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Native solution

The official solution provided with [*Windows 10 Insider Preview Update* (14951)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release-notes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#build-14951) is based on the almost forgotten [*binfmt_msc*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) Linux facility for launching binaries.  The registration command for the *binfmt_misc* would be like this (where `/init` is the provisional *binfmt_misc* "interpreter" for the win-executables):

```
sudo echo ":WSLInterop:M::MZ::/init:" > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

And then win-executable would be launched like regular programs:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32
$ notepad.exe
$ ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2
$ ls -la | findstr.exe foo.txt
$ cmd.exe /c dir
```

> Not that any win-executable must reside in the windows (*DrvFs*) file-system - not on the Linux's file-system (*VolFs*) - in order to inherit a proper *Windows* working-directory.

### The *cbwin* alternative

Untill you get the latest build, project [cbwin](https://github.com/xilun/cbwin) offers a workaround, by installing 3 new linux commands inside WSL:

- `wcmd`: call a win-executable through `cmd.exe`.
- `wrun`: call a win-executable synchronously with `CreateProcess`, and wait to die (not using `cmd.exe`).
- `wstart`: launch a detached (asynchronously) command (with the use of `cmd.exe`).

In order to use them, you must:

1. Install *cbwin*:

   - a new `outbash.exe` will be installed in your regular Windows filesystem (somewhere in your `%PATH%`), plus
   - the 3 linux-commands in the WSL filesystem.
2. Use this `outbash.exe` (wherever you installed it) to start WSL, NOT `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`!
3. Prefix any win-executables with one of those commands, e.g. `wrun notepad`.

**Tip:** If the executable launched with `wcmd` or `wrun` spawns any children, these survive only for as long that executable remains alive.

In other words, trying to start `notepad.exe` with `wcmd` won't work, because *notepad* will be killed just after having been launched -- Use `wrun` (synchronously) or `wstart` (asynchronously) in this case.

Comment: ouch! That's one heck of a work-around, but sometimes that's all we have (upvoted!) . Thanks for sharing.

Comment: With Creators Update (15063), running both command line and GUI exe just works fine.

Comment: I have to use `echo ":WSLInterop:M::MZ::/init:" |sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`, or it will say `Permission denied`.

Comment: but what about the opposite, what if I wanted a sort of binfmt_misc for windows to directly run ELF executables on Windows ?

Answer (score 63):

In the [Windows 10 Creators Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/04/11/windows-10-creators-update-whats-new-in-bashwsl-windows-console/) (build 1703, April 2017), this is natively supported. So you can now run Windows binaries from Linux...

`notepad.exe` or any other `.exe` (the extension is needed and it [needs being on your path](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/more-easily-invoke-windows-apps-and-tools-from-bash-on-windows/), some older versions need the whole path)

...and vice versa using one of the following:

- `bash.exe -c command_to_run` i.e: `bash.exe -c ls`
- `bash -c command_to_run` i.e: `bash -c ls`
- `wsl command_to_run` i.e: `wsl "ls"`; or specify the distro you want to use to run it using:

  - `ubuntu run ls`

For more information, see the above linked article.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that they changed the command from `bash` to `wsl` but it looks like `bash` still works but it might be deprecated.

Comment: note to others: you MUST include the extension and case-correct name on the exe for it to work.

Comment: I can't get that to work in general.  For example, I have firefox installed (`firefox.exe`) but typing firefox.exe at the bash prompt results in `firefox.exe: command not found`

Comment: Oh I see: need to run `/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla\ Firefox/firefox.exe`

Comment: @MeirionHughes What extension do you mean?

Comment: @xotonic calling windows exe's from WSL bash - you need to include the extension i.e. `nodepad.exe`

Comment: @MeirionHughes oh, *file* extension. I completely forgot about it. Thanks :)

Comment: @andrew-mao Can we run tiling manager on WSL to manage Windows app XD

Answer (score 5):

why not just use

```sh
$ powershell.exe Start filename
```

`Start` is the Windows equivalent to `xdg-open` on most linux or `open` on macOS, which means "open with default desktop application". I like to alias it to open.

Comment: Note `cmd.exe /c start`  is the same.

Answer (score 4):

I use alias.

```
alias aws="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2//aws.exe"
alias kubectl="/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/kubectl.exe"
alias kubectx="/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/kubectx.exe"
alias kubens="/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/kubens.exe"
alias pytest=pytest.exe
```

Comment: Did you know that Docker Desktop automatically adds kube commands to the WSL if you enable kubernetes support?

Answer (score 3):

While running an `.exe` from the command line works, when running from say PHP via `exec()` I couldn't get that to work. Adding `/init` , however , does work. This is my working `/usr/local/bin/convert` file for GraphicsMagick installed on Windows:

```
#!/bin/sh
/init "$(ls /mnt/c/Program*/GraphicsMagick*/gm.exe|tail -1)" convert "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit baffled by this. I added a symlink:

```
$ ls -l /c                                                                                               
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Dec  3 10:24 /c -> mnt/c
```

now ls /c gives the same result as ls /mnt/c

But now:
/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java.exe  -version 
==> nothing

However:

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java.exe  -version 
java version "1.8.0_211"                                                                                                Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)                                                                   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

The same thing happens for other windows executables.
Has WSL got a bug implementing symlinks?

Comment: I also tried this - created a symlink to the .exe directly, still no luck.

Comment: Another work around (a bit annoying) for a specific .exe create a proxy bash script -
`/mnt/d/path/to/executable.exe "$@"`
This was enough for me, i just wanted access to windows install of anaconda.

Comment: As of today, 2020-11-09, `/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java.exe  -version` gives me the exact output as having the `/mnt`.