# How is it possible to run .exe from WSL2?

Tags: windows, executable, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I ran `dotnet.exe` in a Ubuntu WSL2 instance, and it surprisingly ran. This is a Windows program, that just ran on an Ubuntu instance. How is this possible? Could someone provide a link to the documentation that explains this behaviour?

[image]

The tool runs from WSL2:

```
❯ dotnet.exe --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: What happens when you actually try to use the tool though? I imagine it wouldn't work as soon as any libraries or syscalls are invoked.

Comment: @wxz It runs fine (see edit)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1525506/why-is-windows-subsystem-for-linux-able-to-run-windows-exe-programs) explains it?

Comment: Also covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920711/11810933) on Stack Overflow.  Short answer - `binfmt_misc` (also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)).  And the official Microsoft [WSL docs on interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop).