# Why is $OSTYPE returning "linux-gnu" on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash

### Problem

When I run a bash script on Windows:

```
bash my_script.sh
```

I get `linux-gnu` for `$OSTYPE` inside the script.
Why is this like this?
I assume that i have WSL installed is relevant here.

Tested in PowerShell and CMD.
Git bash is returning `msys` like expected! Thx @user1934428

### Background

I want to start some python scripts from bash, but not inside WSL.
From my command line I reach different python versions on windows, but from inside the bash scripts it is using the one inside WSL (except for GitBash).

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Do you "just" want to have `OSTYPE = windows` or is that variable actually irrelevant and this question is about accession the python versions installed in windows? Anyways, you cannot run bash from WSL without using WSL.

Comment: @CodePrinz : Which bash implementation are you running? Git Bash or Cygwin bash, or something else? The Python implementation does not matter here.

Comment: Nor does the presence of WSL, so long as you are not running Bash inside WSL.  But if you *are* running bash inside WSL then of course `$OSTYPE` reports `linux-gnu`: WSL provides a container running Linux.  The nature of the host machine is irrelevant to software running within.

Comment: @user1934428 I tried now also in Git Bash and this works!

Comment: @Socowi I want to start a windows python version not inside WSL.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The thing is I didn't want to ran bash inside WSL. I assumend starting in from Windows in PowerShell or CMD will not end up in WSL.

Comment: Then, maybe this answers your question: [How can I run a Windows executable from WSL (Ubuntu) Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38920710/6770384). Instead of calling `python` in bash, call `python.exe` (may need the full path `C:...`).

Comment: @CodePrinz : Forget about Python. Your question relates to bash, not Python. You can run whatever Python you like.

Comment: @CodePrinz : Different bash implementations will likely output a different value for bash. Mine (Cygwin) outputs `cygwin` when asked for OSTYPE. That WSL bash produces _linux-gnu_  sounds reasonable and I wonder why you are worrying about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, running the bash command in PowerShell or CMD will launch WSL to run your script. You confirm this (and see which version of WSL) by running `cat /etc/issue` in your bash script. Your WSL environment will have an independent set of environment variables (not just $OSTYPE). You can see this by comparing the output of `Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\` in PowerShell to the output of `env` (after you launch bash from PowerShell).

I suspect that the python version discrepancy you're seeing is a result of the PATH variable in your WSL runtime not matching what you have set in your PowerShell environment. You can fix your version issue by setting an alias containing a path to the python executable you want to use by adding `alias python=/c/path/to/python.exe` to the start of your bash scripts.

Alternatively, you can use a tool like Cygwin or git-bash to run your scripts. I'm not sure if they will use the same path variables as Windows so you may need to set those manually too.