# Can't run any Python files on Ubuntu(WSL)

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have just started working on my new pc and just to get a feel for it I wanted first to start working on python files, so I started first by just wanting to run WSL on windows and it installed correctly but when I want to run any python using the run python file on the top right on VS code, this is what gets executed `$ C:/Users/jaffe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe f:/Projects/hello.py`
And this is the error: `-bash: C:/Users/jaffe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe: No such file or directory`
I have no idea what's causing it but when I run the file using `'Shift + Enter'` which is: `Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal` it seems to run the single line correctly but it gives me this error instead:

*print("Hello, world")
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello, world"'*

but when I run it using `python3 hello.py`, it works perfectly fine?! I'm so lost as to why this is happening and how could I fix it.

Might be relevant: I'm using windows 10, installed python 3.10.2 from windows store, all of that is in VS code and the python code is one line: `print("Hello, world")` and I changed the permissions of `Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps` so it's now accessible by all users to view/read/edit/run, made sure that `python3.10.exe` exists(on the WindowsApps and it works perfectly) and reinstalled it many times, tired `python3.9`, and tried to install python from the website instead of the windows store and still the same, manually added python to PATH and tried .venv and didn't work. when I launch `python3.10.exe` outside vs code it seems to run perfectly, I have worked with python before and it used to work fine now I don't know what's wrong.

I have seen other questions of the same problem I'm having here but none of them solve the problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to run your _Windows_ version of Python from WSL? I can't imagine any situation where that would be better than (a) running a Linux version of Python in WSL or (b) running a Windows version of Python in Windows.

Comment: Where is VSCode installed? In WSL, or in Windows? Assuming it's in Windows as it probably should be, are you using the Remote-WSL extension?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I'm trying to just use the python extension feature that allows me to run python files immediately without having to worry and mess around to cd into folder and stuff because it gets really complicated in my code

The VSCode is installed in windows and I am using the Remote-WSL extension

Comment: What do you mean by "the python extension feature that allows me to run python files immediately without having to worry and mess around to cd into folder and stuff"?

Comment: *"I changed the permissions of `Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps` so it's now accessible by all users to view/read/edit/run"* - I generally recommend against that unless you are sure you fully understand the consequences.  It's inaccessible under Windows for multiple reasons, including security and stability.  You can always *view* it, at least, in a secure manor using an Administrator shell.  There's just no good reason, IMHO, to make it accessible to normal users.

Answer (score 0):

#### No such file or directory `C:/Users/...`

For **wsl**, the Windows filesystem is accessible, but it has a different path. It is mounted under the `/mnt` folder. So you would find your python .exe under `/mnt/c/Users/jaffe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe`. This said, the executable file is meant to work on Windows, and it doesn't really makes sense to use it on Linux when you could run python within your **wsl** distro.

#### python3 works perfectly fine

This is because most Linux distributions come with python3 pre-installed, so you can use it already. To see where it is located, you can run the command `which python3`, or `python3 --version` to check its version.

If you want to change version, you may consider download it from you package manager, apt.

I also suggest to install `python3-pip` if you don't have it already to get the pip package manager for python.

Comment: "This said, the executable file is meant to work on Windows, you can't really do much with it on Linux"—actually, these days [you can run Windows binaries from WSL just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47663269/354577). Doesn't make much sense to run _Python_ this way, though.

Answer (score -2):

In my case when I ran into this.. I discovered pyenv. This allows you to download more than one version of python. You can then go into a specific directory, such as your python project and issue a python local 3.10.0 (for example). Here's a [link](https://www.adaltas.com/en/2021/06/09/pyrepo-project-initialization/) on how to install it as well as poetry which is a virtual environment manager that is become very popular. You can also create an alias for python that works off of this. I add this command to my alias file and source it from my .bashrc. `alias python='pyenv exec python3'`