# Bash Process Substitution with WSL

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to understand the following (odd?) behavior on my setup. I am running Windows 10, with WSL.

Here is what I see from my powershell+wsl session:

```
$ ./run.sh

Windows IP Configuration
<cut>
1
```

with:

```
$ cat run.sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p dir/1
mkdir -p dir/2
mkdir -p dir/3

var=0
while read i;
do
  ((var++))
  ipconfig.exe
done < <(find dir -type d)

echo $var
```

---

If I now comment out the `ipconfig.exe` line:

```
...
  #ipconfig.exe
...
```

Here is now what I get:

```
$ ./run.sh
4
```

Why calling a [window executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920710/how-can-i-run-a-windows-executable-from-wsl-ubuntu-bash) (eg. `ipconfig.exe`) seems to interfere with my `while` loop using [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13727116/136285)) ?

For reference:

```
$ uname -a
Linux FR-L0002146 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `ipconfig.exe` is reading from stdin, so it's sucking up the input from the process substitution. Redirect its input to `/dev/null` to prevent this.

```
while read i;
do
  ((var++))
  ipconfig.exe </dev/null
done < <(find dir -type d)
```